# How to find a word to fit a meaning?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, dictionaries

I need to find a word that would have a reasonably close meaning to:

> a collection of facts and arguments used to arrive at an explanation [of some (thing|concept|idea|...)]

More generally, I would appreciate if someone can give leads to *how* to create|construct or search for words expressing a given meaning. I've found the [OneLook Reverse Dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml). What other tools are available to achieve this?

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52817/collective-noun-for-facts for a discussion of "A collective noun for 'facts'."

Comment: @JLG: That was an interesting read.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about finding words, if you have a general category to begin with (as you do -- "information"), you can consult *Roget's Thesaurus*. See below for how it's organized. I recommend the print version, but there is also an online version. [Online Roget's Thesaurus.](http://thesaurus.com/Roget-Alpha-Index.html)

From [Wikepedia entry:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roget%27s_Thesaurus)

*Roget's Thesaurus* is composed of six primary classes.[5] Each class is composed of multiple divisions and then sections. This may be conceptualized as a tree containing over a thousand branches for individual "meaning clusters" or semantically linked words. These words are not exactly synonyms, but can be viewed as colours or connotations of a meaning or as a spectrum of a concept. One of the most general words is chosen to typify the spectrum as its headword, which labels the whole group.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the online copy of Roget's, it will definitely be handy. I do have a print copy of it as well (as well as a rather elderly copy of Fowler's Modern English Usage - quite an interesting book to browse through, and quite funny in places)

Answer (score 1):

How about *[findings](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/findings)*?

> b : the results of an investigation —usually used in plural

Comment: Isn't 'findings' a closer synonym for 'explanation arrived at' than for my quoted string?

Comment: I started in that direction, but you said you were looking for a collective noun.  I was going to suggest something like _thesis_ or _research_ initially.

Answer (score 1):

**Premises** might be appropriate, but its hard to tell without context, I don't think there's a cross-discipline word for that.

Comment: It's one of the words I am considering, the others include: conjecture(s?), hypothesis, postulate(s?), but none of them gives that aha!-feel ;) I agree about the context, though the nature of my problem is that it must fit any and all as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In a more mathematical or logical context, the *"collection of facts and arguments"* would be your **proof**

> **noun**
>   1. evidence sufficient to establish a thing as true, or to produce belief in its truth.
>   2. anything serving as such evidence:
>   *What proof do you have?*