# What is a word for when you condense a topic into a work that is all that's needed to understand it?

Tags: single-word-requests

Like when CGP Grey makes a video about [the European Union](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O37yJBFRrfg), that video explains everything with details yet clearly and concisely. I thought ***redux*** would have been a great word, but it only means "revived"

Comment: The *definitive* video?

Comment: That's pretty accurate.

Answer (score 4):

Consider *[quintessential](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quintessential)*

> the essence of a thing in its purest and most concentrated form

Comment: I like quintessential except it applies to examples(mostly human) that fit well to a model rather than describing a talk/text/video.

Answer (score 4):

you can say:

[***compendious***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/compendious) (adj) ***compendium*** (n)

> containing the substance of a subject, often an exclusive subject, in a brief form; concise: a compendious history of the world.

[***succint***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/succinct?s=ts) (adj)

> marked by brevity and clarity; concise

[***precis***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/precis?s=t) (n, v)

> a summary of the essentials of a text; abstract

[***abridge***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abridge?s=t) (v)

> to shorten by omissions while retaining the basic contents: to abridge a reference book.

***epitome*** (n)

Comment: Re *compendium* and   *compendious*, also see [my answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/52826/11433) to [a previous question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52817/collective-noun-for-facts)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context you could use any of:

- [pithy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pithy) (*a pithy explanation of the EU*)
- [summary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/summary) (*in summary, the EU is ...*)
- [executive summary/abstract](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/executive+summary)
- [boils down to](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boil+down+to) (*The EU boils down to ...*)
- [in a nutshell](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+a+nutshell) (*in a nutshell, the EU is ...*)

Answer (score 0):

v.tr. digest, sum up, put in a nutshell, abridge

n. digest, abridgement, abridged version

adj. digested, summed-up, in-a-nutshell, abridged

Do look into the details, because these are not "perfect" synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

I would call that video "The EU *in brief*".

Answer (score 0):

In literary forms, a **Treatise** can often be this kind of work.

Answer (score 0):

I've happened across "cheat sheet" since I asked the question.

Comment: That’s a somewhat different thing, though.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is *epitome*, in the sense of this definition in *The Oxford Universal Dictionary* (1955):

> A condensed record or representation in miniature.

User49727 suggested this term earlier, but didn't supply the particular meaning relevant to the original question.